# Error al usar new para un puntero dentro de una función. c++

Tags: c++

cuando trato de inicializar un puntero con new dentro de una función al momento de ejecutar me da el error segmentation fault

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(int *p)
{
    p=new int();
    *p=2;
}
int main()
{
    int *a;

    func(a);
    cout<<*a;

    system("pause");
}
```

Pero si el new lo pongo en el main fuera de la función ya no me da error, quisiera saber por qué pasa eso.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(int *p)
{
    *p=2;
}
int main()
{
    int *a;
    a=new int();

    func(a);
    cout<<*a;

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el cambio que haces en `func` es un cambio local.

```
void func(int *p)
{
    p=new int();
    *p=2;
}
```

Cuando una función recibe un puntero, lo que sucede es que la dirección de memoria se copia. Esto permite modificar el contenido de dicha memoria y que dichos cambios se puedan observar fuera de la función.

Ahora bien, no hay que olvidar que el puntero `f` en realidad es una copia del puntero `a`. Es decir, ambos apuntan inicialmente a la misma dirección de memoria... pero cada puntero se encuentra en una posición de memoria diferente.

Esto se puede comprobar facilmente:

```
void func(int *p)
{
    std::cout << "Direccion de p: " << &p << '\n';
    std::cout << "Contenido de *p: " << *p << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int *a = new int[1] { 5 };
    
    std::cout << "Direccion de a: " << &a << '\n';
    std::cout << "Contenido de *a: " << *a << '\n';

    func(a);
}
```

Con este ejemplo puedes comprobar como `a` y `f` se encuentran en posiciones de memoria diferentes. Esto quiere decir que los cambios que hagas en `f` no se ven reflejados en `a`, ya que estos cambios no se están realizando en la memoria que comparten ambas variables.

Para poder inicializar `a` dentro de la función es necesario que la función reciba un puntero doble:

```
void func(int *&p)
{
    *p = new int[1]{ 5 };
}

int main()
{
    int *a;
    func(&a);
    
    std::cout << *a << '\n';
}
```

O una referencia a puntero:

```
void func(int *&p)
{
    p = new int[1]{ 5 };
}

int main()
{
    int *a;
    func(a);
    
    std::cout << *a << '\n';
}
```

En ambos casos lo que consigues es compartir la dirección física de `a`, de tal forma que todos los cambios que se hagan en `f` se verán reflejados en `a`. Estás tocando la misma posición de memoria.

En cualquier caso, usar un parámetro para inicializar una variable es una solución poco elegante. Es preferible usar el valor de retorno:

```
int* func()
{
    retur new int[1]{ 5 };
}

int main()
{
    int * a = func();

    std::cout << *a << '\n';
}
```